# Firebase cloud messaging notification not received by device from SNS aws

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am having an issue with FireBase Cloud Messaging in which I get the Token from the device and send the notification test through the Google Firebase notification console getting notification to the mobile.
But am failing to get notification from AWS SNS ?  Please let me know any further information that would be helpful. Thanks.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        //check msz contains data
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        //check msz contains notification

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());


        }
    }


    ////Display notification

  private void sendNotification(String body) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //set sound for notification

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("NewProject")
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0/*Id of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
    }
}


**manifest**

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
    </application>
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIdService.java**

```
 private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseInstanceIdService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        //get updated token
        String refreshedtoken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG,"New Token:" + refreshedtoken);
```

Comment: did you ever figure out the reason?